# Ошибка при получении значения из пустого EditText

Tags: java, android

Создал приложение типа рандома: водишь 2 числа (диапазон) - генерируется рандомное число. Но, если в полях ввода все стереть и запустить приложение оно крашается. Как решить?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public void onButtonClick (View v){

        EditText el1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Num1);
        EditText el2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Num01);
        TextView randText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rand);
        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(el1.getText().toString());
        int num2 = Integer.parseInt(el2.getText().toString());


       // int random_number1 = num2 + (int) (Math.random() * num1); // Генерация 1-го числа
        num1 -= num2;
        int random_number1 = (int) (Math.random() * ++num1) + num2;
        randText.setText(Integer.toString(random_number1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто перед запуском метода проверяете на пустоту или null

```
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(el1.getText().toString().trim()) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(el2.getText().toString().trim()) ){
  //Если условие выполнилось делаете расчет      
} else {
  //в противном случае делает что Вам надо (показываете ошибку и т.д.)
}
```

Comment: при работе с преобразованием из строк в числа недостаточно проверить, что строка пустая, она может содержать строку, которая не является целым числом и тогда программа "упадет". Правильным решением в данном случае все же будет ответ A. Shakhov

Comment: в описании сказано что числа генерятся то есть ввести символ нельзя, в вопросе звучала проблема пустого EditText'a. Можно так же выставить тип клавиатуры только для чисел тем самым убрать возможность ввести строку. Ну и на конец можно делать проверку строки с помощью регулярки на содержание букв. Ловить с помощью catch  - это крайняя мера. ИМХО

Answer (score 3):

У вас вылетает из-за того, что метод `Integer.parseInt` генерирует исключение `NumberFormatException`.

Это как раз потому, что вы на вход этому методу подаёте пустые строки из ваших EditText'ов

Такие ситуации нужно обрабатывать, например так:

```
int num1 = 0;
int num2 = 0;
try {
   num1 = Integer.parseInt(el1.getText().toString());
   num2 = Integer.parseInt(el2.getText().toString());
} catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
   // что-то делаем, если введёные значения не удалось преобразовать в тип int
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, а как собственно этот трай кетч пристроить в код

Comment: @GrandMax13, достаточно поместить код, который может выдать исключение, в блок `try`

Comment: В блоке `catch` логично в поля ввода выводить еррор-сообщение, что необходимо ввести число:`el1.setError("Введите число");`

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) для обработки ситуаций когда в поле не введено ничего или введены не цифры:

```
int num1 = Optional.ofNullable(el1.getText())
                   .map(Editable::toString)
                   .filter(s -> s.matches("\\d+"))
                   .map(Integer::valueOf)
                   .orElse(0);
```

Comment: а можно так ? if (el1.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
 
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); else мой код

Comment: Можно и так, только строку на пустоту лучше проверять методом [isEmpty()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty--).

Comment: С монадами даже красивее) А как в таком случае будет обработано исключение `NumberFormatException`?

Comment: Извените, не понимаю , вот чтото начудил не работает
        } catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
            test = true;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

          if (!test) {
              num1 -= num2;
              int random_number1 = (int) (Math.random() * ++num1) + num2;
              randText.setText(Integer.toString(random_number1));
          }
    }`

Comment: Насколько я понимаю класс Optional доступен с API24. Мало кого устроит такое ограничение в наши дни

Comment: @pavlofff есть же бэкпорты. Например, [streamsupport](https://github.com/stefan-zobel/streamsupport).

Comment: @A.Shakhov значения способные вызвать это исключение будут отфильтрованы одноимённым методом.